# Reaching memory allocation in R

Tags: r

Trying to View a RData file which is 650,000KB and the machine has 8GB RAM but keep getting this error:

Reached total allocation of 7758Mb: see help(memory.size)

> Error in View : cannot allocate vector of size 54.6 Mb

I had initially imported this file (2.5GB) using Read.table with great difficulty due to the size. Code used:

```
A <- read.table(file.choose(),header = TRUE, sep= "|",  fill = T, nrows = 9000000, stringsAsFactors = T)
save(A, file ="A.RData")
load("A.RData")
View(A)
```

Comment: the answer depends on what you need to do when all the data is read. so what do you need to do? modelling? data cleaning?

Comment: Data is clean already, start using it in analysis.

Comment: also forgot to mention that I am fairly new to R!

Comment: what sort of analysis do you have in mind? modelling? you probably need to be very specific on what you want.

Comment: Remove `View(A)` ... I guess you are using Rstudio and you're trying to visualize the data. It's too big, you should visualize a subset of it, e.g. use `head(A)` `tail(A)` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Given the size of your file I would suggest using `ff` and `ffbase` packages and reading directly from the text file with `read.table.ffdf`. This circumvents the memory requirements by keeping the data on the hard drive, but doing operations on it as if it was read in RAM. Unfortunately, there are not that many functions implemented for `ffdf` at the moment, so depending on the modeling you would like to do, you might need to write your own implementations of the tools you would need.

Other than that you might try setting up a hadoop cluster and using `rhadoop` or something, but I'm not really an authority on that.

Comment: They should first try using package data.table. If they don't do something unreasonable (like `View`ing data with several million observations) RAM might suffice.

Comment: See the nrows in the beginning - that is precisely what the asker is doing. Also, as far as I get it, the problem is with reading the file in the first place and I'm not sure data.table can help with that.

Comment: As I said, it's unreasonable to `View` such large data. And it's also pretty useless. data.table's `fread` shouldn't have a problem with reading a 2.5 GB file on a 8 GB machine. However, it is missing a `fill` argument and fortunately doesn't convert characters to factors.

Comment: @martinMarkov , thanks I'll give that a go and hopefully it works.

Comment: By the way, since View cuts its output to the first 1000 rows anyway you can just do `View(A[1:1000, ])` and get pretty much the same thing without the insane memory requirements. You can also cut it to even fewer rows.